# How can I insert time in table 2 that matches time in table 1

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

```
 INSERT INTO purchase_record
        (purchased_from_id, purchase, paid, balance, bank, cheque_no, date,
        cheque_status,time)
 VALUES (
        (SELECT purchased_from_id FROM purchased_from WHERE name = 'Hassan Izhar'),
        (SELECT total FROM purchase_receipt WHERE purchase_receipt_id = '0000001'),
        10000,
        (SELECT balance FROM purchase_receipt WHERE purchase_receipt_id = '0000001'),
        'UBL',
        '1234567',
        '10-JUN-1014',
        'Cleared',
        '(SELECT SUBSTRING(convert(varchar, time,108), 1, 5) FROM purchase_receipt WHERE purchase_receipt_id = ''0000001'')');
```

I tried this query but the following error showed up:

```
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Comment: Your last value is a string literal instead of the result of a query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to construct the properly joined SQL Select statement and insert it into your table, like this:

```
 INSERT INTO purchase_record
        (purchased_from_id, purchase, paid, balance, bank, cheque_no, date,
         cheque_status,time) 
 SELECT f.purchased_from_id, r.total, r.balance, 10000,'UBL','1234567',
        '10-JUN-1014', 'Cleared', SUBSTRING(convert(varchar, r.time, 108), 1, 5)
   FROM purchased_from f
        INNER JOIN purchase_receipt r ON f.purchaser_id = r.purchaser_id
  WHERE f.purchase_receipt_id = '0000001';
```

Please note, that in the above statement you will need to properly define the joining condition. I have put a placeholder `ON f.purchaser_id = r.purchaser_id` (which is obviously incorrect, as I do not know your database schema). Please find out how your purchased_from and purchaser_receipt tables are linked and use a proper column(s) for the join

Answer (score 1):

What's the datatype of your date field? If it's **DATETIME** then it's Date range is
**January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999** and the date that you have passed is '10-JUN-1014' which is out-of-range for this datatype. If you want store this date then you should use datatype as **DATATIME2**.

Also remember the best format for passing the date in SQL is YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 0):

Your datetime format is not according to SQL format..

10-JUN-1014 should be  YYYY-MM-DD 1014-06-10

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `time` column on the `purchase_record` table is of type `Time` try the following:

```
-- Get Purchased From Id
DECLARE @PurchasedFromId AS INT
 SELECT @PurchasedFromId = purchased_from_id
   FROM purchased_from
  WHERE name = 'Hassan Izhar'

 INSERT INTO purchase_record
        (purchased_from_id, purchase, paid, balance, bank, cheque_no, date,
        cheque_status, time)
 SELECT @PurchasedFromId AS Purchased_From_Id,
        total AS purchase,
        10000 AS Paid,
        balance,
        'UBL' AS Bank,
        '1234567' cheque_no,
        '10-JUN-1014' as [Date],
        'Cleared' AS Cheque_Status,
         CONVERT(Time, [time], 108) AS [Time] -- Use 114 instead of 108 for 24 hour
   FROM Purchase_Receipt
  WHERE Purchase_Receipt_Id = '0000001'
```

If `time` from the `Purchase_Receipt` table is the same as `time` on the `Purchase_Record` table, then there is no requirement to `CONVERT`.